# similarity measurement among names?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, word2vec

I have a list of names with me and iam trying to find the most similar 5 names from the list of any given name as a query.
I thought of applying word2vec or else using Text.similar() from nltk.
but iam not sure whether these will work for names as well.

any similarity measure would work for me.
any suggestions?
this not for any project but just i wanted to learn new things.

Comment: Are you after surface similarity or semantic similarity? In the first case, e.g. "Steve" and "Steven" are seen as similar, and you would typically use string similarity measures, maybe combined with some hand-written rules. In the second case, if you use word embeddings, you might find out that the names "Trump" and "Putin" are similar (because these names appear in similar context if the embeddings were trained on news texts).

Comment: Hi @lenz surface similarity will work for me.Any ideas on how to do that.

Comment: I came across this library in python 'difflib'.wil it do my work. any idea.

Comment: `difflib` might be a start. There's a number of possible approaches, and I'm sure for most of them you'll find some third-party Python library: based on minimum edit distance (Levenshtein, Levenshtein-Damerau), based on character n-grams (cosine similarity, Dice coefficient etc.), or based on some kind of hashing (eg. soundex and successors).

Comment: Have a look at [this paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W14-0607)

Comment: You could also check out [this library](https://github.com/universal-automata/liblevenshtein). It is based on the Levenshtein distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you added NLTK, I assume you are fine working in Python.
Check out the [Jellyfish](https://github.com/jamesturk/jellyfish) library which contains 10 different algorithms for comparing strings. Some of them will compare just the characters while others will try to guess how a string would be pronounced and help you identify other phrases that are very differently spelt but would sound similar.
The actual algorithms are all written in C and so this library is pretty efficient!
I think you will find the Jaro-Winkler distance to be most useful. Also check out [this paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~Peter.Christen/publications/tr-cs-06-02.pdf).

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about this tech report by Peter Christen (even though I knew it). It's much better suited as an introduction to string similarity. The pro of Efremova et al. are the nice charts about the separability of the positive and negative classes.